# python fishface = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer() error

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio, face-recognition

I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sam\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 6, in <module>
    fishface = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

for fishface = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer() in python 2.7 (64- bit). I'm using visual studio 2017 and when I ran this with python 2.7 (32 bit) there was no such problem.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

FisherFaceRecognizer file was not present and that's why the problem occurred. Reinstalling opncv2.7 solved the problem.